# GoalSeek only within VBA, without depending on a WorkSheet Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

**Very shortly**: Instead of `ActiveCell` of `ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("GM")`formula, how can I use a variable? So I want to use something like `GoalSickVariable.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("GM")`

.

**As a detail:**

I am trying to shorten my current **GoalSeek** formulation and I'm stucked on the last line.

So far, I was running my codes within WorkSheet but as I can't assume which part of the Worksheet will be empty, I was going to a cell which is away from the reference cell by `.Offset(0,25)` but as user can also use that cell, I would like *not to use any range within WorkSheet* - if it's possible.

```
...  
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ROUNDUP(SellPrice,-3)"
RoundedCellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=(" & RoundedCellAddress & "-" & "SellPrice" & ")"
'SellPrice is a NamedRange from this current Worksheet
ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("GM")
'GM is also a NamedRange from this WS and it changes SellPrice's value.
...
```

While it's a *very bad practice* with many **ActiveCell** and a **Assuming Cell Reference**, this above code is working without any problem. Anyway as I explained above, I don't want to assume this `.Offset(0,25)` cell and don't want to use these **ActiveCell**s.

So here below how I transformed my code into a good practice:

```
  ...
  RoundedSellPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(ws4.Range("SellPrice"), -3)
  GoalSick = RoundedSellPrice - ws4.Range("SellPrice")
  GoalSick.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ws4.Range("GM")
  ...
```

But now as you can easily guess, it gives me **Invalid Qualifier error** on `GoalSick.GoalSeek` line because `GM` and `SellPrice` are variables defined within WorkSheet so they are (*I think*) not able to run GoalSeek formula from VBA module without exactly referring to any cell(contains formula) within the WorkSheet.

If somehow I can not do this formulation without referring to a cell within the WorkSheet, how should I suppose to do without assuming a dummy cell like `.Offset(50,150)` or without creating a new empty WorkSheet?

Comment: I am not sure, but what is "GoalSick" ? is it a typo or have you defined it?

Comment: :) no that's not a typo, I defined it. Firstly I am defining my GoalSeek formulation to that GoalSick variable, then try to run GoalSeek code for that variable.

Comment: ok, you need someone better than me then, cheers.